# Kafka used as Delivery Mechanism in News Feed

Tags: apache-kafka, feed

Can I create topics called update_i for different kinds of updates and partition them using *user_id* in a Kafka MQ ? I've been through this post by confluent.io: https://www.confluent.io/blog/how-to-choose-the-number-of-topicspartitions-in-a-kafka-cluster/ . Also,  I know that I cannot create a topic with dynamic number of partitions. These two facts (the post and static number of Kafka partitions). What's the delivery mechanism alternative ?

Comment: Why do you want to partitioning by user id? Do you want to "subscribe" or process only messages from certain users and not others? Or you are thinking about user_id being the destination user id?

Answer (score 1):

> Can I create topics called update_i for different kinds of updates and partition them using user_id in a Kafka MQ ?

If I understand you correctly, the answer is Yes.

What you would need to do in a nutshell:

- **Topic configuration:** Determine the required number of partitions for your topic(s).  Usually, the number of partitions is determined based on (1) anticipated scale/volume of the incoming data, i.e. the Write-side of scaling, and/or (2) the required parallelism when consuming the messages for processing, i.e. the Read-side of scaling.  See https://www.confluent.io/blog/how-to-choose-the-number-of-topicspartitions-in-a-kafka-cluster/ for details.
- **Writing messages to these Kafka topics (aka the side of the "Kafka producer"):** In Kafka, messages are key-value pairs.  In your case, you would set the message key to be the `user_id`.  Then, when using Kafka's default "partitioner", messages for the same message key (here: `user_id`) would automatically be sent to the same partition -- which is what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

As a possible solution I would suggest to create a number of partitions, and then setup producers to select partition using the following rule

```
user_id mod <number_of_partitions>
```

That will allow you to keep order of messages for particular user_id.

Then, If you need to have a consumer that processes only messages for particular user_id, you can write a (low-level) consumer that will read a particular partition and process only messages that are sent for a particular customer and ignore all other messages.